# jQuery on mouseover and leave

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup, mouseenter

I have the following jQuery, when a list item in my menu is moused over it will find if `.sub-menu` exists and `.slideDown()` and on leave it will `.slideUp()`.

My problem is 2 of the submenus are around 205px high and the third is 54px high and every so often 1 of the larger `.sub-menu` will only goto 54px in height.

Is there a way to improve my jQuery below and also fix the height issue?

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".main-menu > ul > li", function(){
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown();
}).on("mouseleave", ".main-menu > ul > li", function(){
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').stop().slideUp();
});
```

Unfortunately I wont be able to post any html do to the size of the menu.

Comment: I used hover to create a small sample, and cannot reproduce this issue: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNWFY/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".main-menu > ul > li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').stop(true,true).slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen how `hover()` works? One possible solution is:

```
$("body").hover(function(){ $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown(); }, 
function() { $(this).find('.sub-menu').stop().slideUp(); });
```